# I can neither add nor remove a git remote with a specific name, it does not appear in `.git/config`

Tags: git, git-remote

I accidentally reversed the order of some arguments when trying to add an upstream remote to my git repo.

I.e., I input

```
git remote add https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert.git upstream
```

Which led to

```
fatal: 'https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert.git' is not a valid remote name
```

But now,

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert.git
```

returns:

```
fatal: remote upstream already exists.
```

and

```
git remote rm upstream
```

returns:

```
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.upstream'
```

Then,

```
git remote -v
```

I get

```
origin  git@github.com:michaelpacer/nbconvert.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:michaelpacer/nbconvert.git (push)
upstream
```

And when I look in my `.git/config` there is no instance of `[remote "upstream"]`…

So I'm a little stumped.

Comment: I've moved the repository elsewhere and set up a *new* new, clean repo for my own work. If anyone has insight on this, I'm happy to listen and will test it on the old repo, but this seems pretty bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure precisely how this happened, but I believe the problem is that you have a non-empty `[remote "upstream"]` section in your `--global` config (usually `$HOME/.gitconfig` but `git config --global --edit` will bring up the correct file in your editor).  I verified that once in this state, `git remote rm upstream` acts the way you are seeing.

If you clean that out, the normal method of adding a remote named `upstream` should begin working again.  You can use your editor to clean it out, or use:

```
git config --global --remove-section remote.upstream
```

Comment: I would love to know how you figured this out; that seems to be exactly what occurred. Thank you!

Comment: @mpacer: it just seemed likely, given that the remote was showing up but was not in the repository-specific `.git/config`, that somehow it got in the next-level-up file.  (There's also the `--system` file but hardly anyone ever uses that and unless you have a habit of running stuff as root, it should be impossible to write it by accident.)

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this:

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

**Adding additional remote repositories***

```
git remote add <name1> <url1>
git remote add <name2> <url2>
```

**Setting upstream***

```
git remote add upstream <url>
```

Comment: I have an origin repo, and i included the url. The problem is that it will neither let me add nor remove `upstream`.

Comment: Because that's my copy of the repo that i want to push to on GitHub. It is the for the purposes of my development work.  `upstream` I use to refer to the upstream repo. Regardless the weird part is that it won't let me add or remove `upstream`

Comment: I have updated the answer with the upstream addition

Comment: You're missing the source of my problem, please read my question. I literally have that line with the appropriate url included as an example. The problem is that line does not function appropriately.